# merge two vector of void pointer (void *) into resulting new one

Tags: c++, merge, memcpy

If the merge below is confusing, here is what the high level method I am trying to implement:

I have two vectors each `vector<void *>`

say vectorA  = has three elements :  `void * aa, void * ab, void *ac`
and vectorB  = has three elements :  `void * ba, void * bb, void *bc`

the combination is vectorC: three elements:   `void * ca, void * cb, void *cc`
where void * ca is combination of `aa` and `ba`

I have the following code to merge two vectors of type std::vector into a resultant new one:
It is part of my class (QuadTree)

```
void QuadTree::combineInsertData( const vector <void *> &data, size_t numDataTuples, const vector <void *> &addData, size_t numAddDataTuples, vector<void *> &resData){
    cout << "\t\t in combine Function" << endl;
    cout << " \t\tnumDataTuples: " << numDataTuples << endl;
    cout << " \t\tnumAddDataTuples: " << numAddDataTuples << endl;
    for (int c = 0; c != numCols_; c++) {
        resData[c] = malloc( (numDataTuples + numAddDataTuples) * colElemSizes_[c]);
        memcpy(resData[c] ,  data[c] , numDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);
        memcpy(resData[c] + numDataTuples , addData[c] , numAddDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);
    }
}
```

It does not seem to be doing what it should and I am not sure why.
Here is how I use it: (simple manual test)

```
   vector<void *> newInsertData;
    newInsertData.resize(numCols_, 0);  //numCols_ = 3 in my test case
    combineInsertData(insertData, numTuples, allSubdivData, subDivTupNum, newInsertData); 

    cout << "TEST TEST " << endl;
    cout << " insertData[0][400]" << *((double *)insertData[0] + 400) << endl;
    cout << " newInsertData[0][400]" << *((double *)newInsertData[0] + 400) << endl;

    cout << " insertData[0][5]" << *((double *)insertData[0] + 5) << endl;
    cout << " newInsertData[0][5]" << *((double *)newInsertData[0] + 5) << endl;
    cout << " insertData[0][499]" << *((double *)insertData[0] + 499) << endl;
    cout << " newInsertData[0][499]" << *((double *)newInsertData[0] + 499) << endl;

    cout << " allSubdivData[0][0]" << *((double *)allSubdivData[0] ) << endl;
    cout << " newInsertData[0][500]" << *((double *)newInsertData[0] + 500) << endl;
    cout << " allSubdivData[0][1]" << *((double *)allSubdivData[0] + 1) << endl;
    cout << " newInsertData[0][501]" << *((double *)newInsertData[0] + 501) << endl;
```

NOTE:
I am new to C/C++ , any help is appreciated.
In the test code, it seems that only the first memcpy is working while the second is not (From the combine function).

?? question ??
Is it because it is void * so that the line
`resData[c] + numDataTuples` doesn't make sense? as to where the offset should be?

Here is what it prints out

```
TEST TEST                                                                                             |         CHUNK: writing -5.69494e+06
 insertData[0][400]-7.97392e+06                                                                       |         CHUNK: writing -3.51803e+06
 newInsertData[0][400]-7.97392e+06                                                                    |                tup index = 116
 insertData[0][5]-6.83384e+06                                                                         |         CHUNK: writing -5.43468e+06
 newInsertData[0][5]-6.83384e+06                                                                      |         CHUNK: writing -3.03083e+06
 insertData[0][499]-7.83881e+06                                                                       |                tup index = 131
 newInsertData[0][499]-7.83881e+06                                                                    |         CHUNK: writing -6.50737e+06
 allSubdivData[0][0]-6.86119e+06                                                                      |         CHUNK: writing -4.1256e+06
 newInsertData[0][500]649399                                                                          |                tup index = 132
 allSubdivData[0][1]-8.94236e+06                                                                      |         CHUNK: writing -6.67862e+06
 newInsertData[0][501]0
```

**FIXED**
The bug is in this line:

`memcpy(resData[c] + numDataTuples , addData[c] , numAddDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);`

it should be

`memcpy(resData[c] + numDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c] , addData[c] , numAddDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);`  It is what I suspected earlier.

Comment: Can you describe, on a high-level, what you're trying to do when you say "merge"?  The reason why I ask is that it is rare that there isn't already a function, set of functions, algorithms, etc. that do what you're trying to do without having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: simply I am combining two void pointers into one. Except that I have 2 vectors of void pointers where the first entry should be combined with the first, the second with the second ...etc

Comment: Even with your edit, it still doesn't make sense.  A pointer is nothing more than an integer value.  So forget the term "pointer" -- pretend those are ints.  Now what do you mean by merge, given that those are integers?

Comment: I answered your question in the other comment below.

Comment: well the void pointer is like an array pointer but to data type not known at beginning.

Comment: It was the second memcpy as I suspected but didn't try earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug in this line

`memcpy(resData[c] + numDataTuples , addData[c] , numAddDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);`

it should be

`memcpy(resData[c] + numDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c] , addData[c] , numAddDataTuples * colElemSizes_[c]);`

since it is void pointer it doesn't know where copy starts I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative would be simply:

```
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(newInsertData));
```

In general I would encourage delegating work to STL containers.

Comment: not sure this what I need. I don't want to add to the array. I am merging pointers.

Comment: by merging pointers  I mean like merging two arrays. Each array is `void *`

Comment: You have a sequence of values, another sequence of values, and you want to create a third sequence of values that consist of the first sequence, followed by the second sequence.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @Saher poiners are not arrays. You cannot merge pointers like you cannot merge ints.

Comment: @juanchopanza you know what I mean, I mean merging arrays. I want a continuous way of dereference. Since I am copying data from disk placing in memory pointed by a pointer and I want to merge it to the already existing array

Comment: @Saher I know what you mean *now*, but it took many comments and a couple of "wrong" answers. Getting the terminology right helps.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am sorry I am new to the pointers business coming from Java, Python , C# background. Do you know the right approach for this

Comment: @Saher, If what you want to do is merge these two into a third array,you can copy one first and then the other. If back_inserter is too slow(it does a number of checks in every loop iteration), you can do something like:
    NewInsertData.reserve(data1.size() + data2.size());
    copy(data1.begin(), data1.end(), NewInsertData.end());
    copy(data2.begin(), data2.end(), NewInsertData.end());

Comment: that's what I am doing with memcpy , why is it not doing the right thing?

Comment: The problem is probably that you are adding to res[c], which is a reference to an array of tuples, so instead of moving the reference forward within the tuple, you are moving to other elements of the vector res. Can you check this is what's going on?

Comment: res is a reference to array of tuples. res[c] is the void * at c.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you want.  So start with this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Combine(const std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
   std::vector<T> result;
   std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
   std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
   return result;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<void*> v1;
   std::vector<void*> v2;
   // assume that v1 and v2 have data
   //...
   std::vector<void*> r = Combine(v1, v2);
   // Now r has v1 and v2 combined as one vector.
}
```

Admittedly not the greatest, but if this is what you are trying to achieve, note the usage of copy algorithm with the back_inserter.  You can make the code more generic by using iterators and not peg it to only use vector, but I leave that for others to improve.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of PaulMcKenzie's code there is a good read about `back_inserter` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/

Comment: with this does this mean that if v1 had 3 elements and v2 had three elements , then the result will have 6? If that's the case then it is not what I want, I want the result to still have 3. If simply looking at one column (0th for example), and say v1 allocated 10 doubles in that column while v2 allocated 30 doubles. I want result to be able to index `result[0][0]` to `result[0][49]`

Comment: You know, this is getting close to, if not, an XY problem:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem